# Inserting multiple records as an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

```
<input name="name[]">
<input name="email[]">

<input name="name[]">
<input name="email[]">

<input name="name[]">
<input name="email[]">

....
....
```

On submitting a form that includes these fields, I'm trying to build an array that looks like that:

```
array(

  array(
   'name'=> 'name1',
   'email' => 'email1'
  );

  array(
   'name'=> 'name2',
   'email' => 'email3'
  );

  array( ...
  ....
  ....
);
```

The reason of why I'm trying to do this, is that I want to serialize this array and save it into my database as one data entry. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use looping logic

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){
   if(is_array($v)){
       foreach ($v as $sk=>$sv){ 
                $arr[$sk][$k]=$sv;
        }
       }
    }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arr);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your naming:

```
<input name="myform[0][name]">
<input name="myform[0][email]">

<input name="myform[1][name]">
<input name="myform[1][email]">
```

Your data array:

```
$data = $_POST["myform"]
```

Comment: This approach, if you can do it, is much more reliable than rearranging the data once you receive it

Answer (score 1):

To produce the structure you're looking for, you can do:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($_POST['email'] as $id => $email) {
  $data[$id]['email'] = $email;
}

foreach ($_POST['name'] as $id => $name) {
  $data[$id]['name'] = $name;
}
```

That gives you something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => email1
            [name] => name1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => email2
            [name] => name2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => email3
            [name] => name3
        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply serialize the whole `$_POST` and save it.

```
serialize($_POST);
```

Or

```
serialize($_GET);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that leave you with the different input names grouped together rather than in the name/email, name/email ... structure? As well as anything else that might have been POSTed of course